# Spanish for "goat"

Tags: vocabulario, dialectos

I have come across the following translations:

> chivo
>
> cabra
>
> cordero
>
> carnero
>
> oveja

I am positive they cannot all be exactly the same thing. Can someone please help me understand the differences, however minor? And if at all they happen to be the same thing what's the usage preference in Mexican Spanish? Please mention your country/region in your answer to help understand if there's any regional nuance to your usage.

Comment: Have you tried looking them each up in a dictionary? That would be a good first step. [chivo](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=chivo), [cabra](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=cabra), [cordero](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=cordero), [carnero](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=carnero), [oveja](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=oveja). Once you've done that, if you still have questions about the differences or nuances, that will make for a much better question here.

Comment: Flimzy, feel free to go close my question. I had a genuine doubt so asked the question and don't see anything wrong with it here. Anyways, as you can see below, I have already received and accepted an answer so the closing of the question doesn't bother me. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "cabra", that's the most universal word for goat.
The other words are not goat exactly, such as "oveja" is sheep or "cordero" is baby sheep.
I'm from Argentina.
Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! What about chivo and carnero?

Comment: "Chivo" is baby goat and "carnero" is a male sheep.
It's quite tricky since there are several words for similar things.

Comment: In Mexico Chivo is the same as Goat but now Cabra is more used.

Comment: I Spain, at least where I live, a baby goat is called `cabrito`. `Chivo` is normally used to describe a type of beard (`barba de chivo`).